# I have an idea for a security protocol!

Tags: networking, network-protocols, security

Ok guys, So I was watching inception yesterday and I had this idea. I dont know too much about network security or the internet really. So thats what you guys are for, tell me if this is secure or even possible.Its to send secure data over the web by the way.

My Ideas takes the data needed to be send and encrypts it. The data is then split up into little bits and send to the receiver in multiple sockets or connections. A final packet is then sent containing the encryption key. Once the receiver has gotten the information he can assemble the data and then decrypt it.

My idea is that if someone attempted to gather the packets as they were being sent if he only gets part of the data it becomes useless.

So Is this a even secure or has it been done before?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Different sockets or connections will not cause the data to take different routes. An attacker being able to sniff some of the traffic will most probably be able to get it all. So unfortunately this approach won't have any significant security gains.

If you could make sure that different pieces of information needed to read the data (the data streams or the encryption key) are sent in completely different channels (e.g. the data over a DSL internet line and the key through a direct dial-up connection) you would have a security gain, but not to an extent that I would trust for really sensitive data.

Comment: What about bouncing it off multiple severs would that make it any more secure? Or is the attacker sniffing for packets that are incoming on the receivers ip?

Comment: Depends what the attacker aims to do, but usually, yes.

Comment: So in theory if you send each socket thought multiple servers it would be harder to gather all of the data?

Comment: No, because an attacker usually is located near the receiver of the data.

Answer (score 4):

Data is already sent in this way. In modern TCP/IP networks, the packets do not necessarily travel along the same path to the destination.

Comment: He perhaps deserves a point for inventing the modern internet on his own, though ;)

Answer (score 3):

As long as the receiver gets all of the data, someone intercepting the traffic can get all the data.

Answer (score 3):

One of the tenets of security is - don't do it yourself.